# node.js and mocha-qunit-ui: test with asynchronous requirejs dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, qunit

Short description first: The test in the following snipped is never executed:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    test("test", function() {
        ok(true, "okay");
    })
}, 1000);
```

Is there any way not to autostart the mocha-qunit-ui but wait for some asynchronous callbacks to create tests?

---

So, why would I need it this way?

I'm trying to run in-browser-tests for my classes with nodejs and the mocha-qunit-ui. The classes are loaded **asynchrously** by requirejs.

So I could create a test like this:

```
test("test", function() {
    stop();
    requirejs(
        ['Dependency'],
        function(Dependency)
        {
            expect(1);
            var d = new Dependency();
            ok(d.test(), "test");
            start();
        }
    );
 }
```

But I want to run multiple tests on the same class with the same dependencies, so I thought of creating a test object

```
var d = new Dependency();
```

outside of the test. But then the test would be inside an asynchronous call, and therefore is never called.

Comment: i hope you can create test object inside an asynchronous call also

Comment: I call the `test` function inside an asynchronous call, but the test suite finishes before, and therefore this test is never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not terribly familiar with `mocha-qunit-ui` plugin specifically, but [QUnit has a config object](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/) that you can use to tell it not to run until you are ready (so you can load all of your classes, etc first):

```
<script src="path/to/qunit.js"></script>
<script>
QUnit.config.autostart = false; // be sure this is set BEFORE you add your actual tests
require(
    [ "whatever", "your", "dependencies", "are" ],
    function() {
        QUnit.start(); // tell QUnit you're ready to go
    }
);
<script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It turned out I set `autostart` to true somewhere and forgot about it.